# PrinterJob versus DocPrintJob

Tags: java, printing

I need to implement a listener for my printing routine in order to get status from the printer. I am using PrinterJob, but the listener PrintServiceAttributeListener is not sufficient for me. I would like to implement the listener for DocPrintJob instead. How do I convert to DocPrintJob?

Here is my original code:

```
public void print(int bufWidth, int bufHeight, BufferedImage bufImage, String printerName, String doPrint)
 {
   try
   {
     image = bufImage;
     if (doPrint.toUpperCase().equals("YES"))
     {
       PrinterJob printerJob = getPrinterJob(printerName);
       PrintService printService = printerJob.getPrintService();
       //printService.addPrintServiceAttributeListener(this);
       //printerJob.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobMonitor());

       int width = bufImage.getWidth();
       int height = bufImage.getHeight();

       PageFormat pf = printerJob.defaultPage();
       Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
       paper.setSize(width, height);

       double imageableX = fromCMToPPI(0.1);
       double imageableY = fromCMToPPI(0.1);
       double imageableWidth = width - fromCMToPPI(0.1);
       double imageableHeight = height - fromCMToPPI(0.1);
       paper.setImageableArea(imageableX, imageableY, imageableWidth, imageableHeight);

       pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
       pf.setPaper(paper);
       PageFormat validatePage = printerJob.validatePage(pf);

       printerJob.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(), validatePage);       
       printerJob.print();
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you added the according programming language tag (Java?).

Comment: Hi @whizzzkey. No, but since the printer has a SNMP interface, I used this instead.

Answer (score -1):

By calling getPrintService on the PrinterJob you can get a javax.print.PrintService that has a method addPrintServiceAttributeListener which will allow you to listen for PrintServiceAttributeEvents.

Comment: As I wrote in the beggining, the PrintServiceAttributeListener is not sufficient for me. The PrintJobListener is easier to use and delivers simple messages. So I just want to "convert" from PrinterJob to DocPrintJob if posible.

Comment: Could you explain how I can (if i use PrintServiceAttributeListener and PrintServiceAttributeEvents) determine is printerJob completed or not, or got an error?(like it do a PrintJobListener)

Comment: Did you work this out? I need the same, i am currently using PrinterJob but would like to determine if the print was successful or not